# マイグレーションの** MISSING **という表示を消したい

Tags: php, cakephp

言語はPHP、フレームワークはcakephp、dockerを使用して開発しています。

`sh bin/cake migrations status` コマンドを実行した際に、以下の行が出ます。
この行を削除するためには、どうすればよいですか。

```
up  20230529081025  Changetest   ** MISSING **
```